# Keras Determine Wrong Predictions

Tags: python, keras, classification

I have a trained Keras model, and I have a validation set (i.e. X_val, y_val). I want to use the model to predict on y_val, then determine the indices of the wrong predictions. Then, I will use these indices to determine the raw data points that correspond to the misclassifications. How do I get these indices?

My goal is to show a list of raw inputs that we misclassified. This is part of my error analysis. The raw input is text, but that shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: Please explain your claim and provide and alternative.

Comment: Indices have high variance. I assume you're a good data scientist, and I know by extension that you must've shuffled the data around. Instead of going with indices, mark the false predictions from the get go and then analyze.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to compare the prediction where it's incorrect using the model's predict_class.

```
incorrects = np.nonzero(model.predict_classes(X_val).reshape((-1,)) != y_val)
```

Comment: Can you explain what `reshape((-1,))` does and why it is needed here?

Comment: Note, `predict_class` should be changed to `predict_classes`.